# Family History Website

Tags: php, asp.net, open-source

I want to develop a website that has family history information.  Something like Ancestry.com but much simpler.  I want to display photos, family tree, have logins and allow members to upload family photos,documents,stories and comments and have tags for the docs and photos and maybe a message board and blog.

Also, this is not for the general public but just my extended family.  I'd like each person to have their own page with a bio, pics and information.

Is there anything that already does something like this?   I don't want to waste time writing this if it already exists.

thank you

I'm familiar with asp.net and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into a Content Management System, either Drupal or Wordpress.

Both are Free and Open Source Software packages created using PHP.  You can easily make your pages only available to users who are logged in, thereby making the site private.

http://drupal.org/
http://wordpress.org/